# Can't select and click on a div with "button" role

Tags: node.js, dom, puppeteer

I'm trying to click on a `div` that has a `role="button"` attribute,
Even though I'm not using it trying to get it by its DOM path is not working either.

What I've tried:

```
try {
  let Button = await this.page.$("div.class1.class2 > div");
  await Button.click();
  console.log("Clicked");
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  console.log("No button");
}
```

The error I get is:

`TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined`

I tried to get to the `div` by the `div` that contains it which does have 2 classes I can relate on but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to get an array of all the divs with `role="button"` and click only on the one that has a span inside it with a specific text?

Comment: Can you share the html structure of the page you are trying to access?

Comment: The error message you're getting leads me to believe that `this.page` is not defined. Are you sure that it is?

Comment: @TsvetanGanev tthanks man I took it from another bot I made and missed it :D

Answer (score 3):

Remove `this` keyword to fix the `TypeError` error.

```
let Button = await page.$("div.class1.class2 > div");
```

To get an array of all the divs with `role=button` and `Specific text` text:

```
const buttons = await page.$x('//div[@role="button"][text()="Specific Text"]'); // returns: <Promise<Array<ElementHandle>>>
```

But I would recommend adding `waitForXPath` method to wait for the element.

Full example:

```
try {
  const button = await page.waitForXPath('//div[@role="button"][text()="Specific Text"]');
  await button.click();
  console.log("Clicked");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("No button", e);
}
```